# How to match something that begins with and something else that is exactly?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to match the following URIs:

```
/
/login?id=random (random is any number or characters)
/logout
```

but not

```
/anything-else (refers to all other pages)
```

In other words, I need something that matches both `/^(\/|\/logout)$/i` and `/^\/login/i` but not anything else. Is this possible with a single regex?

Comment: Haven't tested it, but what would happen if your regex was `/(^(\/|\/logout)$|^\/login)/i`?

Comment: You could also try `/^(\/|\/logout.*)$/i`.

Comment: @jdwire, surprisingly your first proposal works too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Regex**:

```
^/(logout|login\?id=\d+)?$
```

Tested Regex **[here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)**.

[image: Tested]